# Can I still restore an in-app-purchase which has been disabled from the iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I recently changed my app's business model from one-time purchase to subscriptions model.

Previously, I was selling in-app-purchase A which is one-time purcahse for removing ads.

In the next version, I am going to sell in-app-purchase B which is subscription which removes ads and provides cloud sync function, so I will no longer sell in-app-purchase A in this version.

However, I still provide the restore function for users who bought in-app-purchase A before.

I was asked to remove the in-app-purchase A if I don't sell it anymore in the next version from App reviewer, and I explained my concern for restore, but no reply for this and they just demanded to remove it again, and if I ask again, they usually take 3-5 days to reply...

My concern is that if I disable in-app-purchase A from the iTunes Connect, users who bought the in-app-puchase A before will no longer restore it in the next version, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can always restore that purchase, even it was removed from sale by the app developer.

Removing the purchase will make it only disappear from the App Store display list, great to get rid of sale packages. But the users will still be able to restore that purchase forever.